# How to stop users from holding down enter

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating an incremental/clicker game focused around Poke Balls, and I found a major exploit that could potentially be used to cheat. If the user selects the main image, which is a pokeball, they are able to then hold down the enter key and rack up pokeballs easily. How can I stop this from happening?

Comment: You can tell the difference between a user repeatedly pressing a key and the same key being held down trivially - a key-up event must occur between successive key-down events, otherwise you know the key is being held down.

Answer (score 0):

You can't stop user from holding down enter or any key for that matter. Just bind your actions correctly. If you want to ensure one enter press gives one pokeball on that image use following:

```
    <img id="mainImage" src="/img/logo.png" tabindex="0"/>
```

and in javaScript:

```
document.getElementById("mainImage").addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {

if (e.which === 13) {
    // incresePokeball();    
}})
```